# Iteration variable error in for loop: C program, OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to execute a code in C using OpenMP. The following is the code

```
#pragma omp parallel \
reduction(+:array[length])
{
    int start = 1, distance, nthreads;
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    printf("%d\n", nthreads);
    #pragma omp for   
    for (distance = 1; distance < length; distance = distance + distance) 
    {
        for (i = length - 1; i >= start; i--) 
        {
            array[i] = array[i] + array[i - distance];  
        }
        start *=2;  
    }
}
```

The compiler is throwing the following error

```
**error**: increment expression refers to iteration variable ‘distance’
#pragma omp for
```

I tried to browse about this error online, but didn't find much. Any help in decoding the error would be useful.

Also, should the reduction clause be present on top top next to `#pragma omp parallel \` or after `#pragma omp for`.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenMP `loop` work-sharing construct requires a so called *canonical loop form*. You can only increment the loop variable by a loop-invariant value. You have to restructure your loop, e.g. through use of `sqrt` / `<<`. Also note that your use of `start` is not correct. Compute start from the loop iteration.

Comment: I was using distance *= 2. But this syntax is not allowed in OpenMP loops. How can i achieve distance = distance *2 , in the outer loop for increment?

Comment: You cannot directly use the exponential variable as a loop variable. Instead use the exponent as loop variable and compute `distance` dynamically.